# how to return function/line error in graphql

Tags: javascript, graphql

I currently have a function that's throwing an error, but the graphql error response is a very vague:

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "Expected type ID!, found undefined.",
            "locations": [
                {
                    "line": 3,
                    "column": 23
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

How do I get a more useful error message (i.e. having it return me the stack trace).

Example code:

function.js

```
export async function throwError() {
  throw new Error("I have an error");
}
```

schema.js

```
const graphql = require("graphql");
const { throwError } = require("./function");

const query = new graphql.GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "Query",
  fields: {
    test: {
      type: graphql.GraphQLInt,
      resolve: async function(_, args, context) {
        return throwError();
      }
    }
  }
});

const mutation = new graphql.GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "Mutation",
  fields: {
    test: {
      type: graphql.GraphQLInt,
      resolve: async function(_, args, context) {
        return throwError();
      }
    }
  }
});

const schema = new graphql.GraphQLSchema({
  mutation,
  query
});

module.exports = schema;
```

test.spec.js

```
const graphql = require("graphql");
const the_schema = require("./graphql");

describe("test", function() {
  it("should error", async function() {
    const full_query = `
      query {
        test
      }
    `;
    const result = await graphql(the_schema, full_query);
    expect(result.errors).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

Comment: @xadm No server, I'm just running jest tests

Comment: this error is about detected bad usage (query fields type matching) not failing code/unhandled exception - no need to explore stack

Comment: @xadm yep, found that out just before. Although, after fixing it, and throwing the error, I still can't see proper stack trace. Do you know enough from this vague explanation or should I update the code/respnose.

Comment: expected errors are defined - test passing ;) ... query is a root type, usually returns other types, like userType in this example https://graphql.org/graphql-js/constructing-types/ ... only root types makes no sense, it's not usable